# Rigorous interpretation of $\lim_{\|x\|\rightarrow\infty}f(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, nonlinear-system, stability-in-odes, nonlinear-dynamics

Let $D \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ and let $f:D\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. In nonlinear stability theory, the idea of "radial unboundedness" see, e.g. [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radially_unbounded_function), is important. In most of the literature it is stated that a function is radially unbounded if, for $x\in D$,  "$\|x\|\rightarrow \infty \Rightarrow f(x) \rightarrow \infty$" or something similar, with a definition for the vague premise of the implication given as something similar to "$x$ is taken along any outgoing path / path that goes to infinity."

I am finding this definition too vague to be very useful for actual calculations. So I want to propose the following more precise definition:

**Definition.** Let $D$ be an unbounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. A function $f:D\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is called *radially unbounded* for every real number $a > 0$ there exists another real number $r > 0$ such that 
$
\inf\{f(x) : \|x\| \geq r, \ x \in D\} > a.
$

My question is whether or not anyone else can see any discrepancies between this definition and what is implied by the imprecise definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name *radially unbounded* sounds misleading to me, I would prefer *having limit $+\infty$ at infinity*, but never mind.

Your definition

> For any $a > 0$ there is $r > 0$ such that $f(x) > a$ for all $x \in D$ with $\| x \| \ge r$.

seems all right; it corresponds to Cauchy's "$\varepsilon$-$\delta$" definition of a limit. The *imprecise definition* you're quoting can be made precise as follows:

> For any sequence $x_n \in D$ such that $\| x_n \| \to \infty$ we have $f(x_n) \to \infty$.

This corresponds to Heine's definition of a limit, and it's equivalent to the previous one.

Another (more topological) point of view would be to formalize *limit at infinity* by adding the infinity as an additional point in the domain; this procedure is known as [Alexandrov's (or one-point) compactification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandroff_extension). It enables us to consider $f$ as a function $f \colon D \cup \{ \infty \} \to \mathbb{R}$ (where $D \cup \{ \infty \}$ is a topological space). Then our definition is equivalent to

> The limit of $f$ at the point $\infty$ is $+\infty$ .